# How to hit gmail end points from postman?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, postman, gmail-api

I need to hit gmail end points to send emails and get the email details. I got one url which can be used to send and get the emails i.e. google api explorer. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

But it's not written here about the end points. So somebody please explain what things are required to send and retrieve the email by using gmail api end points through postman?

Answer (score 1):

The end point for sending messages can be found on the documentation page.
 [User.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)  there is also information about the post body.

Upload URI, for media upload requests:

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send

Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests:

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send

**authentcation**

You are going to have to set up authnecation as well.   the easest way to do this will be to use the [Oauth 2.0 play ground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to get a bearer token and apply that to your calls within postman